# ArrayList Bank account basic exercise

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I am new to Java and I am trying to figure out the following method in Java that is supposed to transfer money between objects in an ArrayList (transfer 100 from Account A to Account B.)

No testing has to be made in regards to see if there is an amount in the accounts

I have gotten this far but since it is the last question it is extra hard (atleast for me),

```
public void transfer (ArrayList<Account> List, String fromAccount , String toAccount, double Amount){


  //What is supposed to be in here codewise

}
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: You should probably have a Map<String, Account> instead of a List<Account>. It would then be trivial (end more efficient) to get an account by ID.

Comment: I am supposed to be a student in computing but programming looks to much like hard work. If you do my homework for me, then maybe you'll be allowed the privilege of also paying me to watch you do my job after I graduate.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions based on my *guess* of your problem:

- Likely you'll need a for loop to iterate through the list of Accounts.
- Inside of that loop, find the fromAccount and the toAccounts that correspond to the two String parameters.
- I'm guessing that Account has a `getName()` or similar method that can help you find the proper accounts.
- Be sure not to compare names with the `==` operator but rather with the `.equals(...)` method.
- As @JBNizet mentions, using a `Map<String, Account>` such as a `HashMap<String, Account>`, would make your life much easier and would get rid of the need to iterate through the list with a for loop.
- Then call methods on the two Account objects to transfer money.
- Also as noted by @JBNizet, "make sure not to do this in a single method. Create a method `Account findAccountWithName(List<Account> list, String name)`"

Comment: +1. This is the best answer a question like this can get. Let the OP try to code this by myself.

Comment: +1. And I would add: make sure not to do this in a single method. Create a method `Account findAccountWithName(List<Account> list, String name)`

Comment: Thank you , I just needed guidance on how to proceed.